# CORBA client with multiple network interfaces - bind to specific network interface

Tags: java, corba, orb

I have develop java (jdk5) corba client to receive NotificationIRP proactive events from server. My below code is working fine with single network card. if client system have multiple network interfaces, call back always selecting wrong network card and failed to connect to client. I have tried by specifying `-ORBEndpoint` argument in orb. But still no success.

```
String[] args = new String[2];

args[0]="-ORBEndpoint";
args[1]="iiop://10.106.90.50:9090";   // client eth0              
ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should not specify **any** port number (e.g. in case that port is already bound by another process), but only the IP address. The port number should be chosen randomly by the ORB, from available ports.

Then you can configure this Java property:

```
-Dcom.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost=<IP address>
```

or if you really want to hardcode it:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost", "10.106.90.50");
ORB orb = ORB.init(args, p);
```

*ORBEndpoint* is a configuration for omniORB, not for the Sun/Oracle Java ORB.

Answer (score 0):

Java 5 has long been end of life cycle.  You should be using Java 8 by now.

Which CORBA Java implementation are you using?  The CORBA implementation that bundles with Java itself has a lot of limitation.

I suggest you to check out JacORB http://www.jacorb.org/  It's another Java implementation of JacORB that is still active and being used.

I am not sure if the latest JacORB would work with Java 5, you would need to do some research there.

Once you have JacORB setup, take a look at their documentation.  http://www.jacorb.org/documentation.html  Particularly on the 'Listen Endpoints'and the 'Network Configuration' section.  It should provide the answer you need from there.